# Calculating shortest distance between polygons?

Tags: postgis

I have many polygons stored in a table. I want to filter out polygons where they separate too far away (say 1km).

My approach is:
calculate the minimum distance between a particular polygon to other polygons, and store the value in a new column in the table.

Then filter out polygon with minimum distance larger than 1 km.

I have tried to use:

```
ALTER TABLE "int_20190124" ADD "nearestDistance" float8;
INSERT INTO "int_20190124"("nearestDistance")
VALUES
(
SELECT ST_Distance("int_20190124".geom, "int_20190124".geom)
FROM "int_20190124"
ORDER BY ST_Distance("int_20190124".geom, "int_20190124".geom)
LIMIT 1
)
```

I am very new to postgis.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [ST_ClusterDBSCAN](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClusterDBSCAN.html) to group nearby geometries together and assigning them a cluster id. Cluster ID will be null for single geometries not within the specified distance of another.

Image taken from the help section showing cluster IDs:

[image]

This query should return only the records within 1000 m of Another. `minpoints := 2` is to prevent single points from getting a cluster ID (since they are always within the distance of themselves):

```
SELECT * FROM
   (SELECT *, ST_ClusterDBSCAN(geom, eps := 1000, minpoints := 2) OVER () clusterid
      FROM int_20190124) t1
  WHERE t1.clusterid IS NOT NULL;
```

Example with points and 10000 m distance:
[image]

Comment: Why minpoints := 2 and not minpoints := 1?

Comment: With 1, single records with no other Points nearby will also get a cluster id. Dont you agree?

Comment: Yes, probably. I have always put array_agg(cluster_id) as cluster_ids in the inner select and then used WHERE array_length(cluster_ids, 1) > 1 for this kind of logic, but  your approach is simpler. You should probably explain it in the answer, though, as ClusterDBScan is a bit non-obvious when you first see it +1 anyway, this really is one of my favourite functions, it has so many cool uses, that are really painful to do the old way with spatial self joins.

Comment: @BERA Thank you! Although I still don't understand the query completely, it works! I will study more PostGIS later.

Comment: The underlying theory for DBScan https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN is worth a read. This is a somewhat tricky query as it also involves a window function, https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html, so don't feel too bad if you don't get it immediately. The benefit of a window function is that you can return the actual geometry IDs in each cluster, which was not the case with the original Postgis clustering algorithms, such as, ST_ClusterIntersecting and ST_ClusterWithin.

Comment: another *huge* plus of it being a window function;  you can `PARTITION BY` to effectively cluster over attributes and attribute ranges etc.!

Answer (score 2):

Here is my approach,

It is called "buffer clustering at the required distance"

(do not beat off the fish from the pack at the specified distance, and then we will eat you :-)),

It consists of 6 points, swam...

The source data shown in figure 1
[image]

It is polygons of polygon type. Restrictions, example, are shown without object semantics, so that you can save it yourself.

1. Create a buffer equal to almost half the required distance, for example 501 m:

`create table polygons_byf as SELECT ((ST_Buffer(geography(geom),501))::geometry) as geom  FROM polygons;`

2. Dissolving polygon:

`create table polygons_byf_dump as select st_buffer( (st_dump( st_union( st_buffer(geom, 0.0000000001)))).geom, -0.0000000001) as geom  FROM polygons_byf;`

(John Powell :-)...)

see figure 2

[image]

3. Create the median point to the original polygon:

`create table polygons_byf_centr as SELECT ST_PointOnSurface(geom) as geom  FROM polygons;`

see figure 3

[image]

4. Count the number of points that fall into the combined polygons:

`create table polygons_pt_count as SELECT b.geom, count (*) as cnt FROM polygons_byf_centr a, polygons_byf_dump b  WHERE st_intersects(a.geom, b.geom)  GROUP BY b.geom ORDER BY b.geom;`

see figure 4

[image]

5. Delete polygons that have only one point:

`DELETE from polygons_pt_count WHERE cnt = '1';`

see figure 5

[image]

6. Select only those polygons that meet our condition:

`create table polygons_sel as SELECT ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom) as geom FROM polygons_pt_count a, polygons as b WHERE ST_Intersects (a.geom, b.geom)`

see figure 6

[image]

7. Right now the solution looks like this :-).

Create GEO SQL function:

```
DROP FUNCTION ST_Buffer_clustering_required_distance(
   geom GEOMETRY,
   required_distance float,
   gr_cnt integer)
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ST_Buffer_clustering_required_distance(
   geom GEOMETRY,
   required_distance float,
   gr_cnt integer)
RETURNS GEOMETRY AS
$BODY$
WITH
tbla AS (SELECT (ST_Dump(geom)).geom geom),
tblb AS (SELECT ((ST_Dump(ST_Union(ST_Buffer(geography(geom), required_distance)::geometry))).geom) geom FROM tbla),
tblc AS (SELECT b.geom, count (*) cnt FROM tbla a JOIN tblb b ON ST_Intersects(ST_PointOnSurface(a.geom), b.geom) GROUP BY b.geom),
tbld AS (SELECT geom FROM tblc WHERE cnt NOT IN (gr_cnt))
SELECT ST_Collect(a.geom) geom FROM tbla a WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tbld b WHERE ST_Intersects(ST_PointOnSurface(a.geom), b.geom));
$BODY$
LANGUAGE SQL
```

Run

`SELECT ST_Buffer_clustering_required_distance(geom, 501, 1) geom FROM (SELECT ST_Collect(geom) geom FROM adm_polygons) foo`

And here is the below screenshot and a digital fish that has broken away from the pack in *.svg format, designed using Postgres/PostGIS functions for generating SVG documents, authored by Martin Davis dr-jts - https://github.com/dr-jts/pg_svg.

[image]

Screenshot

(-: FOGS :-)...

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT id
FROM polygons
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT
        p1.id
    FROM polygons p1
    JOIN polygons p2 ON (ST_DWithin(p1.geom, p2.geom, 1000))
    WHERE p1.id <> p2.id
);
```

You can join polygons on [ST_Dwithin](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) to find these being at most one km far from others. Note distance being used is given in SRID units, so be careful when using degrees.

I assume GIST index on `geom` field as well as `PRIMARY KEY` on `id` field exists. As stated in docs, ST_Dwithin includes bbox comparison and generally speaking, it should be faster than building buffers around the input geometries.

Comment: this feature ST_DWithin  automatically includes a bounding box comparison, which is why its use is less accurate, which is why I've abandoned it, but your solution seems interesting to me too, and the abundance of answers enriches the question, respectfully...

Comment: Bounding box comparison doesn't imply function to be less accurate. It implies function to use bbox for prefiltering the data.

Comment: Moving on to the function ST_Expand - what she does ...: -)...

Comment: I may be wrong, but there's buffer bbox is not?

Comment: @Cyril of course there is, but its usage depends on gist built on that buffer.

Comment: By the way, the execution speed of ST_Dwithin is faster than creating buffers around input geometries, we are talking about the accuracy of data processing and, as a result, minimizing errors in the results of these calculations ...

Comment: In general, an idea or a technique is important to me, but for you the speed of the script execution is more important, something like this :-),

Comment: Both the first and the second condition are important for this field of knowledge ...

Comment: @Cyril once again, using bbox comparison to prefilter data does not make accuracy any worse compared to building buffers around input geometries as proposed in some of the answers.